# findAndHookMethod of onInterceptTouchEvent return odd data

Tags: android, touch, gesture, writetofile, xposed-framework

I am using Xposed Frameworkto hook the method: "onInterceptTouchEvent"
This code is running on the background and I am trying to hook every touch gesture in all applications on my Glaxy S4 device.

I am trying to write to a file the data of the MotionEvent Object but when a touch gesture occure in the "com.sec.android.app.launcher" I am getting the Exception: "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

I tried to use synchronized class or put locks on the function but it does not help.

I added "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  so it is not the problem

Another question, why onInterceptTouchEvent somteimes gets onlt ACTION_DOWN?

Here is my code:

```
findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "onInterceptTouchEvent", MotionEvent.class, new XC_MethodHook() {

        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
           MotionEvent motionEvent = (MotionEvent) param.args[0];

           String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

           try {
                File file = new File(path);
                file.mkdir();
                path += "/" + filename;
                file = new File(path);
                CSVWriter writer = null;
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true);
                writer = new CSVWriter(fw);

                writer.writeNext(new String[]{otionEvent.getEventTime() + "",
                     motionEvent.getRawX() + "",
                     motionEvent.getRawY() + ""
                });

                writer.close();



           } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication().getBaseContext(), e.getMessage());

           }

}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to write to a file you may need this permission if you don't already have it     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I added this line... it writes to file all other apps except when I am in "com.sec.android.app.launcher"